# how to write XUNIT test with to the controller

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, xunit, asp.net-core-identity

1. When i am running this code entering valid username and password, still it giving me 404.When i debug the code  Username is showing null.
2. How to write unit test to test the variables inside the controller's Login method, to test the Identity is Null or not.(claims Identity added)

I have written the test code for model state.

I am not getting any clue to initiate the test code. It would be great if someone pushes up.

```
public class AccountsControllers : Controller 
{
    private readonly ApplicationContext appDbContext;
    private readonly IApplicationContext iappDbContext;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;

    public AccountsControllers(ApplicationContext appDb 
        ,UserManager<ApplicationUser> um, 
        IApplicationContext iappdb)
    {
        userManager = um;
        appDbContext = appDb;
        iappDbContext = iappdb;
    }

    [Route("api/login")]
    [HttpPost
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginViewModel credentials)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var identity = await GetClaimsIdentity(credentials.UserName, credentials.Password);

        if (identity == null)
        {
            return BadRequest(Errors.AddErrorToModelState("login_failure", "Invalid username or password.", ModelState));
        }
        var response = new
        {
            id = identity.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "id").Value,
            auth_token = await jwtFactory.GenerateEncodedToken(credentials.UserName, identity),
            expires_in = (int)jwtOptions.ValidFor.TotalSeconds
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response,serializerSettings);
        return new OkObjectResult(json);
    }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GetClaimsIdentity(string userName, 
                                                  string password)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            // get the user to verifty
            var userToVerify = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);


            if (userToVerify != null)
            {

                // check the credentials  
                if (await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(userToVerify, password))
                {
                    return await Task.FromResult(jwtFactory.GenerateClaimsIdentity(userName, userToVerify.Id));
                }

            }

        }

        return await Task.FromResult<ClaimsIdentity>(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: **Don't test the framework.** ASP.NET Identity is already thoroughly tested. You can safely assume it works correctly. If you're wanting to test you custom method `GetClaimsIdentity`, that's a unit test where you just simply test that method. You should not actually activate your login action or even really involve your controller at all. You just pass it a username and password and verify that the return is correct. Done.

Comment: If you can see there is a condition If(identity == null),  i want to test that condition.

Comment: `GetClaimsIdentity` is not shown. Wont know how to mock the functionality of that member

Comment: That's not how testing works exactly. What you're talking about is an integration test. Essentially, you're going mock a request to that action with a test fixure that is a known failure. Then, you simply verify that the response is a 400. The implementation doesn't actually matter (and shouldn't).

Comment: hi Nkosi....i just add claims identity, please check